# How can I Iconize the result of an evaluation so that it isn't overwritten when I repeat the evaluation?

Tags: cells

I have a long calculation that produces a list of lists. I would like to be able to make changes in the calculation, and reevaluate it, and then be able to determine if the result is unchanged. I can Iconize the result at the end of each run, but I don't want to overwrite the previous iconize result. How do I do that?  Ideally, I would add a time stamp to the icon to preserve a series of results.

Comment: The most simple is to give the whole calculation a name. The next calculation of the same thing gets another name. Like this, you do not spoil the first result.

Comment: Write `res1= your calulation..." . The next time you write `res2= new calculation...` e.t.c

Comment: In Daniel's example use an indexed variable, e.g., `res[1] = ...`, `res[2] = ...` You can then easily refer to `n` results by `res /@ Range[n]` or `DownValues[res][[All, -1]]`